# ¿Por que no funciona el selector con corchetes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Genero `input` dinámicos, para después procesar el formulario.

Funciona bien en `JS` cuando las variables las trato sin corchetes así:

```
<input type="text" name="fecha'+x+'" id="fecha'+x+'" size="9" placeholder="Fecha"/>
```

Y obtengo el valor en la siguiente función:

```
function cierre(fila, x) {
  var fechactual=$("#fecha"+x).val();
  alert(fechactual);
```

Pero al trabajar con corchetes...(*lo necesito para `PHP` en `switch($opcion)`*)... ya no funciona, y en el `alert` me dice no definida la variable.

(para probar, he forzado la variable a `fecha[1]`)

```
<input type="text" name="fecha['+x+']" id="fecha['+x+']" size="9" placeholder="Fecha"/>

function cierre(fila,x ){
  var fechactual=$("#fecha[1]").val();
  alert(fechactual);
```

Comment: ¿Cómo intentas usar la variable PHP en JS?

Answer (score 5):

El problema se debe a que los `[]` es un [selector de atributos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), es decir, sirve para "filtrar" por atributos.

### Solución 1:

Necesitas escapar estos caracteres especiales.

#### Opcion 1:

[`$.escapeSelector`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/) (jQuery v3.0+)

```js
var fechactual=$("#fecha" + $.escapeSelector("[1]")).val();
alert(fechactual);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="fecha[1]" id="fecha[1]" value="hola" />
```

#### Opcion 2:

[`CSS.escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape) (`experimental`)

**Polyfill**: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cssesc/1.0.0/cssesc.min.js"></script>`

```js
var fechactual=$("#fecha" + CSS.escape("[1]")).val();
alert(fechactual);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="fecha[1]" id="fecha[1]" value="hola" />
```

#### Opcion 3:

Escapar a mano los `[]`

```js
var fechactual=$('#fecha\\[1\\]').val();
alert(fechactual);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="fecha[1]" id="fecha[1]" value="hola" />
```

#### Opcion 4:

Usar el selector de propiedades `[]` (*gentileza de  @OscarGarcia*)

```js
var fechactual=$('[id="fecha[1]"]').val();
alert(fechactual);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="fecha[1]" id="fecha[1]" value="hola" />
```

### Solución 2:

A `PHP` no llega el `id` del elemento, sino el `name`, por lo que simplemente podrías dejar el `id` sin corchetes.

```
<input type="text" name="fecha['+x+']" id="fecha'+x+'" size="9" placeholder="Fecha"/>

function cierre(fila, x) {
  var fechactual=$("#fecha"+x).val();
  alert(fechactual);
```

Comment: Añade esta otra opción: `$("[id='fecha[" + x + "]']")`

Comment: @OscarGarcia, excelente! He actualizado mi respuesta. Muchas gracias